# How to query inside a postgres db having one column as json value

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a table named Test and in that one column (Subject) contains JSON values.

This is the query which i am using

```
select Name,Subject 
from Test 
where id =1;
```

And the following are the JSON values present inside table.

```json
{
   "subject":{
      "Maths":"20",
      "Physics":"21",
      "English":"22"
   },
   "Staff":{
      "English":"Anna",
      "maths":"Rahul",
      "Physics":"John"
   }
}
```

Now my question is how to write a query to get English mark from JSON value.
Expected o/p is 22.
I am new to postgres, can any one help me in this thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the `->` and `->>` [operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
select Name,Subject, subject -> 'subject' ->> 'English' as english_mark
from Test 
where id =1;
```

Alternatively use the `#>>` operator where you provide the path to the element you want as an array of keys:

```
select Name,Subject, subject #>> '{subject, English}' as english_mark
from Test 
where id =1;
```